# Ldap login in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I want to perform LDAP login in yii2.

How to do this?

This is my function in `LoginForm.php`.

```
public function authenticate($attribute, $params) {
            if (!$this->hasErrors()) {


           // var_dump($_POST); die;

            define('DOMAIN_FQDN', 'abc.com');
            define('LDAP_SERVER', '192.*.*.*');



            $ldap = ldap_connect(DOMAIN_FQDN);

           // echo  $_POST['LoginForm']['username']; 

            if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $_POST['LoginForm']['username'], $_POST['LoginForm']['password'])) {
                    echo "success";
                    die;
            }
            else{
                    echo "error";
                    die;
            }
```

Comment: my platfrom is windows

Comment: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to look at existing solutions before implementing your own.

See this library - [Adldap2](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2).

Here is an example of authentification:

```
try {

    if ($provider->auth()->attempt($username, $password)) {
        // Credentials were correct.
    } else {
        // Credentials were incorrect.
    }

} catch (\Adldap\Exceptions\Auth\UsernameRequiredException $e) {
    // The user didn't supply a username.
} catch (\Adldap\Exceptions\Auth\PasswordRequiredException $e) {
    // The user didn't supply a password.
}
```

More info can be found in README in [official docs](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2/blob/master/docs/authenticating.md). Info about configuring is available [here](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2/blob/master/docs/configuration.md).

As for you latest error, the message is clear - check if credentials that you are provided are correct.